# How to create run time text boxes in WPF?

Tags: wpf, textbox, runtime

I want to create x label and text boxes in run time. x is an integer number. For ex. if x=4, I want to create 4 label and 4 text box in MainWindow. How can I do this?

Comment: use `ItemsControl`

Comment: ItemsControl with a DataTemplate

Answer (score -1):

How about this...

```
public partial class DynamicControlsBench : Window
{
    public DynamicControlsBench()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        int x = 4;
        for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        {
            Label lb = new Label();
            lb.Content = "Label " + i;
            stackPanel.Children.Add(lb);
            TextBox tb = new TextBox();
            tb.Text = "Text Box " + i;
            stackPanel.Children.Add(tb);

        }
    }
}
```

Where...

```
<Window x:Class="WPFBench.DynamicControlsBench"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFBench"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="DynamicControlsBench" Height="300" Width="300">
    <StackPanel Name="stackPanel">

    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```